# Prevent wpa_supplicant from using WPA-TKIP or GCMP encryption protocols

Tags: fedora, security, wifi, wpa-supplicant

Upon reading about the [KRACK attack](https://www.krackattacks.com/) against [WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access), I see this:

> If the victim uses either the WPA-TKIP or GCMP encryption protocol, instead of AES-CCMP, the impact is especially catastrophic. **Against these encryption protocols, nonce reuse enables an adversary to not only decrypt, but also to forge and inject packets.**

Just from looking at the [`wpa_supplicant`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant) man page, I think I can force use of only CCMP by adding this to `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
network = {
    ssid="[REDACTED]"
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
}
```

However, when I restart the network this log message from `/var/log/messages` seems to indicate that TKIP is still being used:

```
Oct 20 17:27:51 localhost wpa_supplicant[1055]: wlp0s18f2u3: WPA: Key negotiation completed with fc:51:a4:4a:43:d3 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
```

A quick `ps -eaf | grep wpa` shows that `wpa_supplicant` is using conf file I edited, and the `wpa_supplicant` log messages shows that it's connecting to the same SSID as in the conf file.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is what I want impossible?

**EDIT**: I'm using Fedora 26 with NetworkManager.

Comment: This has already been patched in Fedora 26: https://fedoramagazine.org/protect-wifi-fedora-krack/

Comment: I believe that what they patched was "Android and Linux can be tricked into (re)installing an all-zero encryption key".  So now Linux is *just* as vulnerable as Windows and Mac, instead of *more* vulnerable.

Comment: As far as I can see, the whole thing is covered by the patch: https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2017-60bfb576b7

Comment: Mathew Cline This is not true. The patch prevents any kind of key reinstallation. However some attacks are still possible if both the client and AP aren't patched. Many routers won't be updated.

Comment: Ah, right.  For details see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/171549/9846

Comment: @jdwolf: It's not the AP point that is vulnerable, the vulnerability happens when the wifi router operates both as a AP point and a wifi client (because then it also uses `wpa_supplicant`, and is exposed to the key reinstallation). So unless you are using your wifi router as some kind of repeater, routers don't need to be updated. The "some attacks" you mention don't exist (or if they do, please give details; I certainly haven't read about them in the KRACK description); it's all about the "trick wifi client into key re-installation".

Comment: @dirkt
"Currently, all modern protected Wi-Fi networks use the 4-way handshake. This implies all these networks are affected by (some variant of) our attack." - Mathy Vanhoef, https://www.krackattacks.com/

It's true the attack 'targets' the client and a network device is often both an AP and a client like in the case of a repeater. But any AP that accepts a vulnerable client compromises its own network and the expectations of other wifi clients because from the unpatched APs perspective it has no idea the client has been compromised.

Comment: @jdwolf: APs don't choose which client they accept, nor can they identify "vulnerable" and "invulnerable" clients. There's nothing you can do to an AP to somehow mitigate the KRACK weakness. What you can do is to patch clients. All of them, including those used in routers. But if the router doesn't use the client that is part if it, it's not particularly urgent to do so. If you don't believe me, please show me a patch to an AP (hostapd or whatever) that somehow helps.

Comment: @dirkt Take a look here:
https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/commit/?id=6f234c1e2ee1ede29f2412b7012b3345ed8e52d3
Furtheremore the client and AP could for example use an entirely different EAP that would not allow vulnerable clients. The reason there is hesitance to patch the APs is because most approaches are not backward compatible.

Comment: @jdwolf: Note the "this workaround is disabled by default". If it was so necessary it surely would be enabled by default ... I also don't see how it prevents the "zero key" attack - the attacker fakes the key installation retransmission, not the AP. Sorry, not convinced.

Comment: @dirkt When you said "There's nothing you can do to an AP to somehow mitigate the KRACK weakness." that was wrong as the commit shows. I don't need to convince you beyond your own standard. I already explained why this would not be enabled by default: "because most approaches are not backward compatible." and this is explained in the patches description. Not much else I can do to convince you. But I can say as a security researcher the AP shouldn't be relying on a handshake that can't guarantee there isn't a MitM. If you want to discuss this further we better move it to chat.

Answer (score 0):

The CCMP is the mandatory data integrity protocol in WPA2  (encryption mechanism based on strong cryptographic algorithm AES) , Your Access Point should be protected with WPA2(AES)-PSK mode.
To verify it run:

```
wpa_cli
scan
scan_result
```

You should see `[WPA2-PSK-CCMP]` under your access point.

The security searcher has posted a script to test your access point for the key reinstallation attack a.k.a krack attack [krackattacks-test-ap-ft](https://github.com/vanhoefm/krackattacks-test-ap-ft).

The patch for [wpa_supplicant and hostapd](https://w1.fi/security/2017-1/) is available and applied through the regular update.

Update to hostapd/wpa_supplicant v2.7 or newer, once available.